# executing a test in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, exec

When I am executing following ...

```
EXEC 'DROP TABLE bkp_anish_test'
```

(`'DROP TABLE bkp_anish_test'` is a dynamically build sql query)

I am getting following error

> Could not find stored procedure 'DROP TABLE bkp_anish_test'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use EXEC to run the sql statement. In the query editor, just run

```
DROP TABLE bkp_anish_test
```

if the table is in xyz database, try this

```
 EXEC ('USE xyz ; DROP TABLE bkp_anish_test;');
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DROP TABLE bkp_anish_test'
```

or for the case of a dynamically built string:

```
declare @MyTable nvarchar(100)
set @MyTable = N'bkp_anish_test'

declare @sql nvarchar(100)
set @sql = N'DROP TABLE ' + @MyTable
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding parentheses to your command.  You must include them when running a SQL statement, if you're going to use the EXEC command.

```
EXEC ('DROP TABLE bkp_anish_test')
```